# Binding label to selected listbox value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Relatively new to WPF and binding. I have a Listbox filled with values. When a user selects a certain value I want to display details of that value over several labels and a textbox. The current LINQ query that fills my listbox list gets the whole table, so the data is inside that list. How do I go around passing the details of the selected value inside of a label?

My current code for the listbox is :

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="LBController" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.Row="1"
         ItemsSource ="{Binding AllControllers}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedControllerID}" 
         SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" >
</ListBox>
```

If a value inside of the listbox is selected, I would like its name to be displayed on a seperate label

```xml
<Label x:Name="lbl_controllername"
       Content="Controller Naam" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
       Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Corsiva" FontSize="11" Margin="40,0,0,0"/>
```

EDIT : Thanks for the answers everyone. This does however seem to prove difficult when doing the same thing with a control that has a function behind it.

```
        <TextBox x:Name="txt_CodeDetail" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                 FontFamily="Corsiva" 
                 FontSize="11"
                 Text="{Binding ControllerCode, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

For example I have a textbox, the text inside of it is converted into a string for a function the app does. This string is called ControllerCode. This was done by copy-pasting the code before but I want the textbox to be filled with a selected property from the value inside the listbox.
I can't use

```
Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Property Elementname=LBController}"
```

as that would get rid of Controllercode and ruin the function. How can I bind the textbox text to the selecteditem as well as maintain the string that is formed with controllercode?

Comment: `Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=LBController}"` should work. There might however be a "selected item" in your view model.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display several properties of an element in some area of the window, then it is easier in this area to set a panel in which the data context is bound to the selected element.
And inside this panel, set a set of elements to represent the properties of the selected element.

Example:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=LBController}">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstProperty}"/>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding SecondProperty}"/>

   <!--Other elements-->

</StackPanel>
```